# Error when i run sudo su on ubuntu 12.04.5 terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, ubuntu-12.04, sudo

I get this error message and after the terminal wants me to enter password. How can i fix this ?

```
sudo: unable to resolve host veargl14855
```

Comment: Check this link, it should give you enough information to help you resolve this issue:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/59458/error-message-when-i-run-sudo-unable-to-resolve-host-none

Answer (score 0):

Two things to check (assuming your machine is called my-machine, you can change this as appropriate):

That the /etc/hostname file contains just the name of the machine.

That /etc/hosts has an entry for localhost. It should have something like:

127.0.0.1    localhost.localdomain localhost
 127.0.1.1    my-machine
If either of these files aren't correct (since you can't sudo), you may have to reboot the machine into recovery mode and make the modifications, then reboot to your usual environment.

more answers are [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59458/error-message-when-i-run-sudo-unable-to-resolve-host-none)